# CSS animation creates flickering on Firefox browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have given customize css animation to bootstrap modal, but on firefox browser some lining coming when I open a modal. Please see below image for better understanding.

[image]

I have written a code in below snippet whatever I did. Please note this is a dummy snippet for just code sharing.

```css
.fade-in.in {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay:0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-name:admin-popup-fadeIn;
    -webkit-animation-name:admin-popup-fadeIn;
}

.fade-in.in .modal-dialog{
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-delay:1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-name:admin-popup-fadeIn;
    -webkit-animation-name:admin-popup-fadeIn;
}

@-moz-keyframes admin-popup-fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility:hidden;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility:visible;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes admin-popup-fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility:hidden;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility:visible;
  }
}

@keyframes admin-popup-fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility:hidden;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility:visible;
  }
}

.modal-content {
    border: 5px solid #5fb9e4;
    margin-top: 10%;
    background-image: url(http://www.dummocrats.com/reagan/reagan_lone_plane.JPG);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    color: #101e54;
}

button{margin:40px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click here</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade-in" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

When I run this snippet on Firefox; flickering not happens. I don't know what is happening in my application so that lining are coming. Please help me if you have any idea that what is affecting my code.

Comment: so how could we reproduce your issue to check it?

Comment: I don't have idea what is happening I have used same code for animation only design change are there. Do you have any idea about css animation flickering.

Comment: Your code seems fine, can't reproduce it in codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWEevx

Comment: when I am adding transform: translate3d(0,0,0) to modal-dialog then that lining are going but now problem is I want vertically center modal-dialog

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in using `translate3d`. This will force hardware acceleration, and in many cases fix flickering issues.

To vertically center your modal-dialog you can set the `top` to 50% and the second parameter in `translate3d` to -50%. Like this:

```
.modal-dialog {
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0);
}
```

In the code you've provided you also have to remove unnecessary margins in order, to center the modal correctly:

```
.modal-content {
  margin-top:0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

It's still very hard to fix your problem since you haven't shared your "real" code but a "dummy" instead. So please try the above out, and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried this way also, when I am adding transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0); this code then again that lines are coming.